# How to write sub query within join query?

Tags: sql-server

When I write the below query

```
SELECT Op.MRNO,
       M.PatientName,
       (
           SELECT COUNT(MRNO) AS Visit
           FROM HMS_Reg_OPRegister
           GROUP BY MRNO
       )
FROM HMS_Reg_Patient M,
     HMS_Reg_OPRegister Op
WHERE Op.MRNO = M.MRNO
```

I got this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Am not getting what are you trying to do, What is your desired output ? Can you give us the tables structures ?

Comment: You should probably take a peek at this article even though it isn't directly related to your question. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Op.MRNO,
       M.PatientName,
       Op.Visit
FROM dbo.HMS_Reg_Patient M
JOIN (
    SELECT MRNO, COUNT(MRNO) AS Visit
    FROM dbo.HMS_Reg_OPRegister
    GROUP BY MRNO
) Op ON Op.MRNO = M.MRNO
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you want:

```
SELECT M.MRNO,
       MAX(M.PatientName) AS PatientName,
       COUNT(*) AS Visit
FROM HMS_Reg_Patient M
JOIN HMS_Reg_OPRegister Op ON Op.MRNO = M.MRNO
GROUP BY M.MRNO
```

It's not necessary to use a subquery to get a count of the number of values in a group, when you already have the table you are counting in the main query.

Comment: Yup, I get you. This how we used to join the tables. But i dont understand where did he joined the tables in his question

Comment: @Ramkee: In the question, the OP is using the older, implicit join syntax - where tables are listed together, separated by commas, and the join conditions are included in the WHERE clause. The linked article in Sean's comment on the question expands on this.